# trying to click on a text with selenium java

Tags: java

am trying to click on a text which will redirect me to a wizard.
Throwing following error:

```
 Unable to locate element: "method":"link text","selector":" Create New Groupings
```

I have tried following code

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
driver.findElement(By.linkText(" Create New Groupings ")).click()
```

html is

```
 <div class="hyperlinkstyle ng-binding ng-scope" ng-click="launchWizard()" ng-if="isAdmin"> Create New Groupings </div>
```

Comment: Does that div is within iframe?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your choosing the right frame which contains the div item.

And then use the following:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@ng-click='launchWizard()']")).click();
```